# Rails + Rolify: Singleton Pattern / Only one Role per User per Resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rolify

I am currently setting up my role management in my Rails app with the Rolify gem - both with the latest versions.

In my case, a user can only have one role at the same time for one specific resource. This means, that before I do a

```
user.add_role :lead, @resource
```

I would like to delete all maybe already existing roles. Unfortunately something like

```
user.current_role.remove @resource
```

is not existing. I only could loop through all maybe existing roles, check if it is existing and delete it. This sounds ugly to me. Stuff like

```
user.roles = []
```

does not help either me because i want to delete all roles for a specific resource.

Is there any standard functionality in rolify to support something like this?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Callback methods to the rescue!

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify before_add: :before_add_method

  def before_add_method(role)
    # do something before it gets added
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up wanting a more substantial solution which removed all kinds of roles from the resource. I made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/Genkilabs/dc94a833b21044b3d4d760c2206cb045) out of it:

**user.rb**

```ruby
class User < ApplicationRecord
    rolify :strict => true, :before_add => :before_add_role

  #Helper method to remove any existing role this user has for a resource
    def remove_all_roles resource
    # README: This syntax relies on changes on the following PR
    # https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/pull/427
    # Or include the source of this directly:
    # gem 'rolify', :git => "git://github.com/Genkilabs/rolify.git"
        remove_role nil, resource
    end

protected

    #ensure that we only have a single role per resource
    def before_add_role(role)
        if role.resource
            Rails.logger.debug "User::before_add_role: Adding the role of #{role.name} for #{role.resource_type} #{role.resource_id} to user #{id}"
            #remove any pre-existing role this user has to the resource
            remove_all_roles role.resource
        end
    end
end
```